# Check if array value is equal to string

Tags: ios, if-statement, swift, nsarray

I am getting a result from my API in the form of a `NSArray`:

```
func JSONAPIResults(results: NSArray) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.loginResult = results
        })
    }
```

My question is, how do i use a `IF Statement` in order to check it against a `String`?
For example, checking if `self.loginResult[0]["result"]` is equal to "Success"

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried simply `self.loginResult[0]["result"] == "Success"?`

Comment: Absolutley @Undo, this generates: `Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '($T8, StringLiteralConvertible)'`

Comment: If you know that the object at that point in the JSON will always be a string, try `if (self.loginResult[0]["result"] as String) == "Success"?` Tell me if it works and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the object at that point in the JSON will always be a string, try casting the value to `String` before comparing it to get rid of the `cannot invoke == with argument list` error:

```
if (self.loginResult[0]["result"] as String) == "Success"?
{
    ...
}
```